# Few-shot learning with GPT4All results in hallucinations

Tags: openai-api, langchain, chatgpt-api, large-language-model, gpt4all

I have setup llm as **GPT4All** model locally and integrated with few shot prompt template using LLMChain. The few shot prompt examples are simple [Few shot prompt template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAEXZ.png).
I have tried the same template using **OpenAI** model it gives expected results and with **GPT4All** model, it just hallucinates for such simple examples. (I know that OpenAI models paramater are huge but still why is GPT4All results are so terrible.

**OpenAI**:

```
from langchain.llms import OpenAI
from langchain.chains import LLMChain

llm = OpenAI(
    model = "text-davinci-003",
    temperature = 0
)
openai_chain = LLMChain(llm=llm, prompt=few_shot_prompt_template)
```

**GPT4All**:

```
from langchain.llms import GPT4All

local_path = "./models/ggml-gpt4all-j-v1.3-groovy.bin"
llm = GPT4All(model=local_path, verbose=True)
gpt4all_chain = LLMChain(llm=llm, prompt=few_shot_prompt_template)
```

**OpenAI** model results:[OpenAI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHz68.png)

**GPT4All** model results:[GPT4All](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDPCY.png)